# Should the HBase region server and Hadoop data node on the same machine?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Sorry that I don't have the resource to set up a cluster to test it, I'm just wondering to know:

1. Can I deploy hbase region server on a separated machine other than the hadoop data node machine? I guess the answer is yes, but I'm not sure.
2. Is it good or bad to deploy hbase region server and hadoop data node on different machines?
3. When putting some data into hbase, where is this data eventually stored in, data node or region server? I guess it's data node, but what is the StoreFile and HFile in region server, isn't it the physical file to store our data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. RegionServers should always run alongside DataNodes in distributed clusters if you want decent performance.
2. Very bad, that will work against the data locality principle (If you want to know a little more about data locality check this: http://www.larsgeorge.com/2010/05/hbase-file-locality-in-hdfs.html)
3. Actual data will be stored in the HDFS (DataNode), RegionServers are responsible of serving and managing regions.

For more information about HBase architecture please check this excelent post from Lars' blog: http://www.larsgeorge.com/2009/10/hbase-architecture-101-storage.html

BTW, as long as you have a PC with decent RAM you can set up a demo cluster with virtual machines. Do not ever try to set up a production environment without properly test the platform first in a development environment.

Comment: RegionServers do store data, otherwise it would be impossible to serve the data that was written to WAL and before flushed to dfs.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Indeed, RegionServers do store (intermediate) data, I've corrected the post. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @RubénMoraleda, thank you for the answer. I have an existing hbase cluster with 3 servers, Server1: hbase master+datanode+zookeeper. Server2: Regionserver+datanode+zookeeper+secondarynamenode. Server3: Regionserver+datanode+zookeeper. So, this is not a good deployment, right? Since on Server1, there is no regionserver, but it has a datanode.

Comment: @morven You should be careful when mixing roles, I assume your hadoop namenode is also on Server1 and it's not recommended to run a it alongside a datanode. That leaves you with 2 possible datanodes / regionservers. A typical hadoop + hbase configuration with a replication 3 factor requires at least 4 servers: one hadoop namenode + hbase master, and 3 datanodes + regionservers. In your case you'll have to use a replication 2 factor to make it work with  just 3 servers. http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.2/bk_getting-started-guide/content/ch_hdp1_getting_started_chp3.html

Answer (score 2):

To go in more detail about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27797264/1915448):

> 1. RegionServers should always run *alongside?* DataNodes in distributed clusters if you want decent performance."

I'm not sure how anyone would interpet the term *alongside*, so let's try to be even **more** precise:

1. What makes any physical server an "XYZ" server is that it's running a program called a daemon (think "eternally-running background event-handling" program);
2. What makes a "file" server is that it's running a file-serving **daemon**;
3. What makes a "web" server is that it's running a web-serving **daemon**; 
   AND
4. What makes a "data node" server is that it's running the HDFS data-serving **daemon**;
5. What makes a "region" server then is that it's running the HBase region-serving **daemon** (program);

So, in all Hadoop Distributions (eg Cloudera, MAPR, Hortonworks, others), the general best practice is that for HBase, the "RegionServers" are "co-located" with the "DataNodeServers".

This means that the actual slave (datanode) servers which form the HDFS cluster are each running the HDFS data-serving **daemon** (program)
**and** they're **also** running the HBase region-serving **daemon** (program) as well!

This way we ensure *locality* - the concurrent **processing and storing** of data on all the individual nodes in an HDFS cluster, with **no** "movement" of gigantic loads of big data from "storage" locations to "processing" locations. Locality is vital to the success of a Hadoop cluster, such that HBase region servers (data nodes running the HBase daemon as well) must **also** do all their processing (putting/getting/scanning) **on** each data node containing the HFiles which make up HRegions which make up HTables which make up HBases (Hadoop-dataBases) ... .

So, servers (VMs or physical on Windows, Linux, ..) can run **multiple** daemons concurrently, often, they run dozens of them regularly.

Comment: This would work better as an answer by removing the implicit direct reference to the other current answer; this is not a forum, with replies on a thread, but a Q&A site, and each answer needs to be independent.